# GCM issues below Android 4 in a library Project

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

So, I have this really weird issue with GCM on devices running on lower versions of android. I have an android library project with GCM enabled. I export it as a jar and then include it in a test application. It works fine with devices and emulator for api level 17 and devices get registered successfully but it doesn't work below that. Now here is the weird part:  If i run the library project as a standalone project, it works fine on all devices including api level 10. Does any one has any idea of what could be the reason ?

Note: Using a library is important for me.

**Edit:**
This is what i get in my log cat:

```
    D/GCMRegistrar(505): resetting backoff for com.example.gcmtest
    V/GCMRegistrar(505): Registering app com.example.gcmtest of senders 378013620721
```

and no further response.

Comment: Doesn't work? can you be a bit specific please? Do you receive any error message ?

Comment: Try [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) code definitely helps you....  You might be missing this one `<!-- GCM requires Android SDK version 2.2 (API level 8) or above. -->
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />`

Comment: @kartheek I already have these settings in my test application manifest file.

Comment: @Shobhit let me update my question

Comment: Where is the class that extends `GCMBaseIntentService` as far as I know this should be in the base backage

Comment: That just shows that it is trying to set a backoff. It retries in case of a failure. Wait..Are you using the new way of getting the ID or the old way?

Comment: @bogdan That class is inside my library project's root package and i have specified its full path inside the test project manifest file. bw if that was the issue it shouldn't work on newer devices either.

Comment: @Shobhit Puri i am doing it like this:                             final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context);

Comment: There's not enough info in your question. Please include your manifest, broadcast receiver and intent service. In addition to that, please specify what exactly fails. Does the registration fail or the receiving of the GCM messages? If the registration fails, what errors do you get?

Comment: Thank you  @Eran. See my answer to this question. It would be great if you could explain why i had to do what i did to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i figured it out myself. Just in case someone else faces this issue in future;
i'll try to explain what the issue was.
So i had a library project with GCM integration say **com.test.gcm-library**. I wanted to use this library in another application project say **com.example.gcmtest**. By following the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212275/register-gcm-from-a-library-project) i managed to to use the library successfully in my **com.example.gcmtest** project. It worked fine with API level 17 but when i tried it with api level 10, none of the GCMIntenetService methods would get called and no response would be generated as i posted in my question but i managed to fix it finally. The trick was to change the intent category for receiver in the manifest file. To be precise, i changed the receiver declaration in the manifest file of   **com.example.gcmtest**         from this:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.test.gcm-library.MyCustomBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.test.gcm-library" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

to this:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.test.gcm-library.MyCustomBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.example.gcmtest" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I don't know why but the receiver category field looked like a "dont care" condition for API 17 but for lower APIs this is what i had to do to make it work.

Comment: I don't know why the category makes no difference in API 17. I have an API 8 device, so it has always been important for me to define everything correctly (according to the GCM docs) in the manifest.

Comment: I had given reference to the root package of library project because  it contained the custom GCM broadcast receiver and intent service definition but it seems like it looks for the host application root package. Am i right ?

Comment: Hello @sayed.jalil can you please guide me to setup this process of receiving push notification from library project. I need help asap, thanks!

Comment: @Harish you just need to add all the reference (i.e define permissions and receivers etc) in the the host application project (the one that's referring to the library project).

Comment: I had done this but still not receiving any push, please can we chat?

Comment: sure. between, did you use the new GoogleCloudMessaging api (that comes with SDK) or the old GCM jar file ? and also it would be better if you could post your manifest file

Comment: Can you please send me your skype id if you are using or gmail-id for chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48335/discussion-between-sayed-jalil-and-harish-godara)